# What happens to subscription if you don't assign it to a variable?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure out why all of the Angular apps I look at assign subscriptions to a variable, only to have to unsubscribe via ngOnDestroy(). For example:

```
export class ViewBookPageComponent implements OnDestroy {
  actionsSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(store: Store<fromRoot.State>, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.actionsSubscription = route.params
      .select<string>('id')
      .map(id => new book.SelectAction(id))
      .subscribe(store);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.actionsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

What happens if I just remove actionsSubscription altogether? Will a subscription still be created but not destroyed? In the below case, you still get the side-effect, but don't have to bother unsubscribing. So is actionsSubscription necessary for garbage collection?

```
export class ViewBookPageComponent {

  constructor(store: Store<fromRoot.State>, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params
      .select<string>('id')
      .map(id => new book.SelectAction(id))
      .subscribe(store);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, if you remove `actionsSubscription` altogether, the `subscription` will still be created but you won't be able to `unsubscribe` from it via `ngOnDestroy`, after you leave the component. If not unsubscribed, the `observable` might still keep streaming data, even after moving away from the component, hence causing memory leaks. So, assigning an observable subscription to a variable and forcing `unsubscribe` ensures that the data stream from that observable is stopped when component is destroyed.

I learned more about `unsubscribe` from this [article](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/) by Brian Love.

One important thing I noted from it -

> if you are using observable streams via the `AsyncPipe` then you do not
>   need to worry about unsubscribing. The async pipe will take care of
>   subscribing and unsubscribing for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! One other question: What if I drop the .subscribe() altogether, and just leave the .map() in place with the SelectAction side-effect? Would the observable keep emitting, or would it die with the component since there'd be no subscriber?

Comment: From angular.io, "The subscribe() method returns a Subscription. A Subscription is not another Observable. It's the end of the line for Observables. You can't call map() on it or call subscribe() again. The Subscription object has a different purpose, signified by its primary method, unsubscribe." In short, observable will not start working until its been subscribed to using subscribe().